# Mysql is not connecting after some time

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

I am using quartz job to fetch records for every 10 minutes.My job is running successfully for 2 hr.after 2 hr i am not able to connect to mysql.it saying below error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2019-11-12 20:30:08 ERROR DbUtils:44 - error during creating mysql connection ,stacktracesun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2095)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2020)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
com.network.assets.airwave.DbUtils.createConnection(DbUtils.java:34)
com.network.assets.airwave.AirWaveService.getDevices(AirWaveService.java:384)
com.network.assets.airwave.AirWaveService.loadDeviceIpListMemory(AirWaveService.java:45)
com.network.assets.core.api.impl.AssetLiveJob.execute(AssetLiveJob.java:158)
org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

if i stopped the application and start again,it running successfully for 1 or 2 hr again i am getting the same exception.

Note:

I wrote simple java code to connect to db  as another application.i ran that its connecting successfully.but it giving a below warning,

```
Tue Nov 12 19:16:04 IST 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

Development environment i am not able to reproduce the issue.

any idea?.

Comment: running out of connections ? Make sure you close them.

Comment: @ScaryWombat,If running out of connection mean it should connect after some time(when connection is avilable),max number of connection in my env is 1500.i checked the connection in mysql it never crossed 300.

Comment: A few years ago I had a similar problem (DBCP connection were being closed) where the network connections to mysql were all showing as TIME_WAIT

Comment: I fixed the issue,the root cause is internally i am opening redis connection .it is not closed .it exceed the number of opened files in linux.so its  not allowing any tcp connection.thats why its not connecting to mysql.